# Google reCaptcha v2 not working after build Angular project with node.js port

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, recaptcha

I am developing an angular application. In my angular application I have included google map and google reCaptcha 2 with angular reactive form. It's working fine with Angular port 4200 but It's now working after build the Angular project while I am trying to run the angular dist folder by node.js server port. It's giving the error below:

**fused to load the script 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LcXVm4lAAAAAGKhBXJsz_c3iY2_ncfuPSwg1jtN&onload=ng2recaptchaloaded' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.**

[image]